# PGRouting: build path without shortcuts

Tags: postgis, pgrouting, dijkstra

I create a pathfinding algorithm using `pgrouting` library. This is the output I get with `pgr_dijkstra`:

[image]

However, I do not need the shortcuts I'm having here.

What are the possible approaches to make sure the red path will be built right down on a blue line?

Basically, I dynamically generate paths from a grid point:

```
SELECT node.id
    FROM (
      select row_number() over () as id,
          point from public.point6
        ) node
    JOIN (select row_number() over () as id,
        foo.id as source, bar.id as target,
        st_makeline(foo.point, bar.point) as point
    from (
      select row_number() over () as id,
          point from public.point6
        ) foo
      join (
        select row_number() over () as id,
            point from public.point6
        ) bar
      on st_dwithin(foo.point, bar.point, 4)
        and foo.id <> bar.id) edg
      ON (node.id = edg.source OR    -- Only return node that is
          node.id = edg.target)      --   an edge source or target.
    WHERE edg.source != edg.target   -- Drop circular edges.
    ORDER BY node.point <-> $1    -- Find nearest node.
    LIMIT 1;
```

Actually, the points have been interpolated from linestrings using this function:

```
ST_LineInterpolatePoints(geom, 3 / st_length(geom)) where id = id;
```

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works

Comment: can you add the query you are running to create that line? It looks like you are not adding the start and end nodes of the segments

Comment: This looks like your network topology is not correct. Could you explain how you created your topology?

Comment: IanTurton, @dkastl, updated data on your request.

Comment: Add the code as text, not screenshot

Comment: @BERA, corrected it